# Standardizing signals from the same experiment setup with different recording tools

Tags: signal-analysis, statistics, time-series, normalization, multi-channel

I've been looking to merge two datasets I have, that capture instances of the same phenomenon using two different recording tools. Both are multichannel electrical signals, but the recording tools have very different properties.
I want to standardize those measures to make them hardware independent, but sadly I can't find much litterature on this topic even though it seems to be quite important to me.

I currently look at two different paths : caracterising the signals using time-frequency analysis, and figuring out the properties of my devices in a controlled environment to extrapolate a transformation to standardize the signals.

I am of course not expecting a definite answer on such a vague problem, but I would be very thankful if any of you can provide guidance or useful papers for me to read.

Comment: A very first (maybe quite naive too) approach would be to try to "cancel" your hardware. Briefly stated this means that you have to deconvolve the hardware's Impulse Response (or Transfer Function if done in the frequency domain) from the measured data.

Comment: It's an interesting idea. Is there any possible generalization to non linear (but still time invariant -probably-) systems ?

Comment: @marpuech generally, yes. You basically would need what is called an *equalizer* in communications technology to compensate your "channel" (i.e., the measurement device). There's equalizer approaches for nonlinear channels, BUT: Nonlinear channels are typically mathematically impossible to invert, and thus to perfectly compensate, especially in the presence of measurement noise. There's sadly no universally "optimal" approach for this! However, when you have a mathematical model for your device, your signal of interest and ideally noise, you can often find something that works well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a "one size fits all" answer for this. Here is one possible process assuming that your goal is "if I measure a system with both tools I should get the same result".

1. Start with the requirements. What information/data exactly do you need and how good does it need to be. Could be transfer function, spectra, THD, noise analysis, Volterra series, etc.
2. Build a few test cases that a) have known answers and b) are reasonably representative for your desired application space.
3. Apply both recording tools to the test cases
4. Check to which extent the recording tools can provide the results and the accuracy you are looking for.
5. Check whether there is enough overlap between the outcomes to standardize on one output format that both tools can produce with reasonable agreement and accuracy. Depending on how the tools and differ and what you need this may requires significant compromise or may not even be possible
6. If that did converge, test verify the outlier use cases.